# Any aggregate functions that allow DISTINCT *?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Some functions allow the `*` notation in an aggregation function, such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales
```

And other functions allow a `DISTINCT` modifier within the function call, such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IF(x > 0, x, NULL)) FROM sales
```

My question is if any functions allow for the notation of:

```
SELECT function(DISTINCT *)
```

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but keep in mind that `DISTINCT` is mainly a set based operation.  How would this be defined against e.g. a scalar UDF?  Also, you can always do a dedupe operation inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, except for the specific case of `COUNT()`, you can't use `*` in function arguments.

- Some built-in functions (for example, CONCAT() or COALESCE()) take a variable number of arguments, but you must spell them out when you call the function.
- In MySQL, stored functions take a fixed number of arguments.
- In PostgreSQL, stored functions can accept a variable number of arguments, but you must still specify them when you call the function.

I looked in the parser code for MySQL, and found these cases of the use of the `'*'` symbol:

- `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(ALL *)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT *)`
- `SELECT * ...` or `SELECT ident.* ...`
- `DELETE * ...`
- `INSERT INTO ident (ident.*) ...`
- `SHOW COUNT(*) WARNINGS` or `SHOW COUNT(*) ERRORS`
- `GRANT ... ON *` or `GRANT ... ON ident.*` or `GRANT ... ON *.*`
- Arithmetic multiplication operator

Comment: "*Stored functions take a fixed number of arguments.*" - not true for Postgres

Comment: And ANSI/ISO SQL does not allow a _set quantifier_ (ALL/DISTINCT) for `COUNT(*)`. (Or a `*` as in any of the above DELETE, INSERT, SHOW or GRANT.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks, I have edited my answer to include that information.

Comment: @jarlh, Yep, as I noted above, those are cases of `'*'` in the MySQL implementation.